# Getting Elements of an Array with a Textbox (JS Validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textbox

I am taking elements of an integer array from user with a textbox. So the textbox should allow only numeric data and comma.

Something like `5,12,4,53,3,0,1` is acceptable.

I simply disallow all keys except `comma`, `numeric`, and `backspace`:

```
    function ControlForArray() {
                if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
                     event.keyCode == 44 || 
                     event.keyCode == 8) 
                {
                    event.returnValue = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

The point is that, I also need to prevent entering **multiple commas** one after another. And **last value should be numeric** (when textbox has unfocused or submit button is clicked).

In this case: `5,3,,4` or `5,3,4,` are also should not be allowed.

How can I do this with js or jquery. Thanks for help.

Comment: last value should be numeric? when ever the user inserts a comma last value becomes a comma. so when does adding values end? you need to be more specific.
BTW did you try anything at all?

Comment: @TilwinJoy thanks for reply, it can be remove last comma when submit button clicked or unfocused from textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Using this RegExp for example:

```
/[\d*,]*\d/g
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/bbuecherl/d6txG/ (this is all native javascript, no jQuery required)

Answer (score 0):

The requirement that the last value should be a number is kind of tricky here so I decided to suggest a two-step approach:

```
var re = /[0-9]{1,2},?/g;
var str = "5,12,4,53,3,0,1";
var myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
typeof(parseInt(myArray[myArray.length-1])) === "number"  // you can use an if statement here
```